# Handling multiple incoming UDP connections with single socket

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, udp

I'm using C++ and want to know whats the best way to handle multiple incoming UDP connections. When I mean multiple it can be a few hundreds or even thousand. Currently Im using a while loop with recv, the data and the IP address of the connection is stored into an array. So there is a chance a few connections getting lost. So is it possible to do this with a Single socket? If I use multiple threads is there a chance a single connection getting accepted by sockets in multiple threads? Here's what I have so far, Thanks!

```
    time_t timeout = time(NULL);
    vector<string> ip_list;

    while(time(NULL) <= timeout + 60) {
        if (recv_len = recvfrom(ser_sock, recv_data, recv_size, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_info, &cli_size) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("[WARNING] recv error occured.\n");
            continue;
        }

        if(strcmp(recv_data, "Save IP") == 0) {
            ip_list.push_back(inet_ntoa(cli_info.sin_addr));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There are no connections with UDP, just data packets going around. Why do you think using a single socket and a loop would cause data loss?

Comment: UDP protocols need to allow dropped packets.

Answer (score 0):

> want to know whats the best way to handle multiple incoming UDP connections.

Be careful with your thinking here. There are no connections in UDP. There are simply packets sent by hosts.

> Currently Im using a while loop with recv, the data and the IP address of the connection is stored into an array.

Have a look at the `select` system call. This is designed for waiting on one or more file descriptors (sockets).

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html

> So there is a chance a few connections getting lost.

You mean there is a chance of *packets* being *dropped*. This is the nature of UDP. Any application you build on UDP must expect that some packets are lost, and that packets will arrive in a different order to which they were sent.

> So is it possible to do this with a Single socket?

Yes

> If I use multiple threads is there a chance a single connection getting accepted by sockets in multiple threads?

UDP sockets are not "accepted" in the sense that TCP sockets are. I would advise against the use of multiple threads until you understand the domain completely.

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker, it seems you have misunderstood some what I said. I do know that UDP is connectionless. And the chance of packets getting lost. What I meant by connection in your first quote is the data sent by the client. And in last quote what I meant is if sockets in multiple threads will recieve the same packet send by one client.  Thanks.

Comment: @DunuraDulshan threading won't normally help as you will be IO-bound rather than CPU-bound. If you must use multiple threads, receive on one thread and hand off to others.

Comment: So still doesn't help if the socket receives multiple packets from different clients? Only one will be accepted and the rest dropped?

Comment: If you have multiple threads receiving on a single UDP socket, then each incoming UDP packet will be received by one of the threads; it's impossible to predict which one.

Comment: @DunuraDulshan no, the IP subsystem buffers incoming packets. If they arrive at the interface and you deal with them in a timely fashion, you won't lose any.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **select**() system call to manage multiple descriptors under some pressure-insensitive circumstance, and **epoll**() for heavy-load system.

BTW: different  from TCP descriptor, there is no acceptance before using it. So you should know exactly the peer or broadcast address.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. So I can handle multiple sockets and recvfroms with select, without multithreading?

Comment: Hey bro, thanks for your reply. When using select or epoll, you should build up a set containing all descriptors, and system will manage them for you. When reading or writing available, you will get notification from select or epoll. One difference between them is that you must traverse the set before knowing which descriptors are dedicated to r/w when using select and that you know exactly the r/w descriptors. Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: @DunuraDulshan one more thing, select or epoll is not really multithreading. Well you also could build up a multithreaded model to do the same task if you wish:)

Comment: So if I open up multiple sockets and include the them into a select block will I be able to do the receiving with all the sockets?

Comment: @DunuraDulshan exactly. And you’ll get notified if data arrives. Just inspect them.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into em